# Why isn't the div draggable after being appended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<div class="simulator"></div>
<div class="1D-Kinematics">
    <button class="square"> Summon Square </button>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable(); // Dragging Function
    $(".square").click(function(){
        $('.simulator').append($('<div id="draggable" class="draggable-entity">')); 
        $('.simulator div').html("");
        // should create a draggable colored div in .simulator
    });    
});
```

CSS

```
.draggable-entity{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: red;
}
```

what happens is that a colored box does appear, however it is not draggable. If i were to plainly put a div with that ID and class in the html, it works and is draggable.

Comment: call `$("#draggable").draggable();` after `div` is appended

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach the draggable() functionality

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
```

after appending the div into the DOM

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".square").click(function() {
    $('.simulator').append($('<div id="draggable" class="draggable-entity">'));
    $('.simulator div').html("");
    $("#draggable").draggable(); // Dragging Function

  });

});
```

```css
.draggable-entity {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="simulator"></div>
<div class="1D-Kinematics">
  <button class="square">Summon Square</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ohh can you explain why it must be attached into the function? The ID was defined outside the function so I didn't think it was necessary to do that. Also thank you very much it works now!

Comment: The draggable function require the element to present on the DOM. If you attach it before appending the element in the DOM the functionality will not get attached.

Comment: to explain more  The selector $("#draggable") will not return any element until its appended to DOM. If you attach draggable functionality to it before appending the element in the DOM, the functionality will not get attached.